# How to substitute a text block in column mode in Sublime Text 2/3

Tags: sublime-text-2

Given a highlighted/copied block of columnar text that is on say 10 lines. The objective is to overlay that area on top of a different set of 10 rows.

Well what happens is when you "paste" in Column mode it creates **100** rows - 10 copies of the highlighted text.

How to achieve the simple overlay required here?

**Update**: I found a mention of using Shift-L or Shift-R.  That does take care of making 10 rows instead of 100.

However when pasting, i now get a different issue: which is that maybe 6 to 8  of the lines go exactly as placed, but the others end up pasted somewhere incorrectly in their respective overlay lines.  That is happening even though the target area has uniform / equal length lines.

[image]

[image]

The first screenshot shows the selected/copied text. Second screenshot shows the "target": notice that **some** of the cursors are aligned before the stringified date but others are too far to the left or right.

I suspect actually this is a bug in Sublime - does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: can you post an image or something to demonstrate? I'm having a hard time visualizing what's going on...

Comment: @MattDMo ok there ya go

Comment: thanks. Sorry, I got nothing for you right now - I haven't come across this before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here may well be "for column mode buy Ultredit".  I will likely continue to use SublimeText as well.